# Behavior of PlotLegends

Tags: plotting, syntax, legending

I want to have a plot of $x^{\alpha}$, where $\alpha$ is an input, and a plot legend which displays something like $\alpha = \# \text{ rad}$ on the following plot, where # is determined by the input. I tried to do this in the following way:

```
Plot1[\[Alpha]_] := 
 Plot[{x^\[Alpha]}, {x, 2, 3}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x" , "y"}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 25], 
  PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[{Style["\[Alpha] = " \[Alpha] " rad", 20]}, {0.7, 0.3}], 
  GridLines -> Automatic]
```

However, instead of the desired result for, say, $\alpha = 2$ (Plot1[2]) the legend reads "2 $\alpha$ = rad". How to force it to display correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`Row`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row.html) to build the display equation, rather than having

```
Style["\[Alpha] = " \[Alpha] " rad", 20]
```

use

```
Style[Row[{"\[Alpha] = ", \[Alpha] , " rad"}], 20]
```

In the first example you have a `Style[Times[...]]`, where you are multiplying the value and the string.